# How can I catch errors dropped by Sharp?

Tags: nestjs, sharp

I'm using Sharp to squeeze images into webp format, but if i put corrupted file it gives an error which I cannot catch and my server goes down.

As you can see below i'm calling "on" event which allow me to throw an error and I see it in console but server goes down anyway.

```
async makeWebpThumbnailForImageMedia(
    inStream: internal.Readable,
    outStream: internal.PassThrough
  ): Promise<internal.PassThrough> {
    try {
      const pipeline = sharp().on('error', () => {
        throw new Error('Error while making webp thumbnail');
      });

      pipeline.resize(800).webp({ effort: 3 }).pipe(outStream);

      inStream.pipe(pipeline);

      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => outStream.on('finish', resolve).on('error', reject));
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    }
  }
```

Comment: I think the server is going down cause you make a try catch, which is good, but in the catch part you throw a whole NEW error. So your server cannot do anything else than throw Error "globally". Instead, you could just make a 
```console.error(error)```

Comment: So the problem is that for corrupted files the server goes down or does not go down? And what is the desired behavior than in case of failure? What would you like it to do?

Comment: @Hades Hey thanks for replying, I want to keep server running and throw this error to front and catch it there somehow.

Answer (score 1):

If you call an `async` function and that async function throws an error that you don't catch, your application crashes.

For your case, probably you manage to catch the error but in your `catch` block, you throw another error which is causing the crash.

You need to handle cases like that properly for your needs. You can log the error or you can notify your client about that or anything you need.